# How can I find the other root of a quadratic equation with 1 root and a unknown b value?

Tags: roots, quadratics

The information I was given was, "If $6x^2 + kx -42 = 0$ has one root as $\frac{-7}{6}$, then what is the other root?

Comment: Welcome to Maths.SE! Please show us your effort, instead of just asking questions.

Comment: Use Vieta's relations.

Comment: Hint:  divide by $6$.  Now, express the constant term as a function of the roots.

Comment: Well.  By the quadratic equation the two roots are $\frac {-k\pm \sqrt{k^2 +4\cdot 6\cdot 42}}{2\cdot 6}$.  $\sqrt{k^2 + 4\cdot 6\cdot 42} > |k|$ so $\frac {-7}6 =\frac {-k-\sqrt{k^2+4\cdot 42}}{2\cdot 6}$.

Comment: I would recommend you to notice that

$$6\left(-\frac{7}{6}\right)^{2} - \frac{7k}{6} - 42 = 0$$

Once you have the value of $k$, you can find the other root.

Answer (score 1):

$$Product\space of\space roots= \frac{-42}{6} =\frac{-7}{6}(x)$$ where $x$ is the unknown root. You get $x=6$ from there.